# How to block OSX logout and do some operation before it logoff

Tags: macos, authentication, macos-mojave

In mac osx when user logouts from it, I want to do certain action to make it graceful.
I added my code in

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
  // do some housekeeping

}
```

But my code is not completely executing, I want to block logout until my operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `applicationShouldTerminate` delegate function.

The return value of that function is `NSApplicationTerminateReply`. If you want to prevent termination, simply return `NSTerminateCancel`. To delay termination, return `NSTerminalLater` and then call `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate` once you are ready to exit.

Here's a simple example in Objective C that will delay the termination by 5 seconds:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(5);
        [NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];
    });

    return NSTerminateLater;
}
```

Comment: This is not blocking system  logout , this is blocking app termination when system is active but during logout it continues to power off and NSterminateLater is not able to block logout

Comment: I put the above code in a new, empty project on my Mojave system and it works as expected. `NSTerminateCancel` shows a dialog box to the user that the app is preventing logout. `NSTerminateLater` blocks the logout for the duration of the sleep. This is the mechanism to do what you want on macOS.

Comment: Make sure you are not blocking inside `applicationShouldTerminate:`. Is your app a status bar app (`LSUIElement` set to `YES`)? This [thread](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Feb/msg00331.html) suggests it won't work.

Comment: Yes my application is status bar app (LSUIElement set to YES). Then this solution won't work ?. What do you mean by this statement "Make sure you are not blocking inside applicationShouldTerminate:"

Comment: I removed LSUIElement set to YES from info.plist but still logout is not blocked. If not in applicationShouldTerminate:, where should I block?

Comment: Make sure that you return from `applicationShouldTerminate:` without doing some long running task inside the callback. If you need to perform a long running task, ensure that you run it on a thread or dispatch queue, like in the example I posted.